# Cauchy distribution won't converge to normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Let $X_n$ be i.i.d. Cauchy sequence, $S_n:=\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{d_n}$, where $\{d_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

**Prove that:** no matter how we choose $\{d_n\}$ from $\mathbb{R}^+$, $S_n$ will not converge to any normal r.v. $N(a, \sigma^2)$ in distribution.

If we choose $d_n=\sqrt{n}$, the convergence of $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is actually the necessary condition for $X_n$ to be square-integrable. Since for Cauchy distribution $E[X_1^2]=\infty$, $S_n$ won't converge to a normal r.v.

But how to prove the situation when $\{d_n\}$ is picked randomly from $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: characteristic function and [Lévy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem).

Comment: For any $d_n$ you have $S_n$ having a (scaled) Cauchy distribution. In particular, the variance of $S_n$ is always infinite for any finite $d_n$ no matter how fast it grows.

Comment: Just looking at variance is not enough: The sequence  $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $Y_n = G+\frac{Z}{n}$, where $G$ and $Y$ are independent $G \sim N(0,1)$ and $Z$ has mean 0 and infinite variance, converges to $G$ with probability 1 even though $Var(Y_n)=\infty$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.